# Does the address of variable says its position in the RAM?

Tags: memory, stack, ram

I know the concept of LIFO,push,pop.

If a code returns the address of a variable as `2245781` , assuming Decimal, does that really mean the variable is on the `2245781st` byte on the stack ? And, if I convert it to *Gigabyte* will that be within the used amount of the RAM at that instant ? If not, why? Is it the same for heap too ?

Just curious..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the address of a variable is its location in RAM, which is often virtualalized on modern desktop-class systems. So two processes can have a variable at *the same* address, since all they see is the virtual address.

In general, again for modern desktop-class systems, addresses for individual variables won't often be odd, although it can happen.

No, it's not indexing into "the stack", all addresses typically look the same and the stack is not different. There is not a separate address space for things on the stack, the stack is a thing in memory just like any other.

I don't understand what you mean by "convert to gigabyte".

Comment: when you say about virtualization, you mean one variable used by two processes, with different address value for each process, but being same in the memory ? I know stack lies in the memory itself, but what I meant was if I can convert the `byte value` of the address printed, it should always be less than or equal to the used bytes in the main memory ,assuming the printed address was the actual address itself, not a virtual one, (if my first statement in this comment  was right).

Comment: No, the other way around. Processes (generally) don't share memory, so the variables will be in distinct locations in the physical memory. But the virtual addresses of the variables might well be the same, since they are virtual it looks to each process as if it is alone in memory. And no, there's no guarantee that addresses are allocated from 0, so you can't interpret an address like that. For virtual addresses there is often randomization, which makes them even more opaque.